# Adding and configuring Column control sightly component

Tags: aem

When I add column ctrl component in geometrix media site, I'm unable to see parsys/responsivegrid only. I has just "Start of (2/3/4) Columns" and followed by "end of columns". There is no "Drag components here" . But this works fine when I add in gemetrixx demo site. can you please help??

Thanks, Raghava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column control components works for the Geometrixx Demo site because the Allowed Formats have already been configured under the design path. For example: `/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/homepage/par/colctrl`.

As part of the sample content, the Geometrixx Media site column control has **not** been configured. To configure it, enter `Design` mode and click `Edit` on the column control. Enter the following values in the Allowed Formats field (sample only):

```
2;cq-colctrl-lt0    2 Columns (50%, 50%)
3;cq-colctrl-lt1    3 Columns (33%, 33%, 33%)
4;cq-colctrl-lt3    4 Columns (25%, 25%, 25%, 25%)
5;cq-colctrl-lt4    5 Columns (20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%)
```

Once you go back to `Edit` mode, you should be able to configure the Column Layout property of the column control component using the drop down.

More information:
http://www.6dglobal.com/blogs/creating-column-control-adobe-cq-2012-02-07